# Powershell GUI & loop pauses

Tags: loops, powershell, powershell-3.0, pause, gui-testing

What I want: my script/program(?) To do stuff on button press then wait if conditions are meet and display how long is left.

Whats happening: When I use 'Start-Sleep' it pauses the GUI and doesn't display how long is left until the very end when it displays all of the text at once.

I've attempted to look for something online and came up dry. I've attempted for, while, and do-until loops all act the same way. So I'm hoping there is another way to pause a loop.

This is basically the script I'm using:

```
$btn.add_click ({
    Foreach ($_ in $stuff)
    {
        #do stuff
        If ($x -eq $y)
        {
            $n = 30
            While ($n -gt 0)
            {
                $textbox.text += "$n seconds left`n"
                ###WAIT 1-5 SECOND(s)###
                $n --
            }
        }
    }
})
```

Comment: Hi, check [this](https://foxdeploy.com/2016/05/17/part-v-powershell-guis-responsive-apps-with-progress-bars/) out (WPF)

Comment: @sodawillow seems like it may work, I'll give it a shot

Comment: @sodawillow it's gonna work for me. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Thank you [@FoxDeploy](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1238413/foxdeploy) :)

Comment: Are you using the form for other advanced input options? If you want to show progress without a form you can use `Write-Progress`

Comment: @Craig620 I'm not sure what you mean by advanced but I'm using textboxes and radio buttons, but that's pretty much it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Here is](https://foxdeploy.com/2016/05/17/part-v-powershell-guis-responsive-apps-with-progress-bars/) a very comprehensive tutorial by [@FoxDeploy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1238413/foxdeploy) that helps you build your WPF GUI in a way that allows commands to be triggered from the UI without freezing it.

I don't share any code here because there is really too much of it.